# Proper way to convert SQL results to JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js

I am creating a API using nodejs. The API takes request and responds in JSON

For example:
I have a table QUESTION in my database so a GET request to endpoint http://localhost/table/question will output the table in JSON format.

However there is a problem when performing JOINS

Considering tables QUESTION and CHOICE. A question has many choices (answers) their join will be

Table:

[image]

I am trying to convert to something like this

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "QUESTION":"If Size of integer pointer is 4 Bytes what is size of float pointer ?",
      "OPTION":{  
         "A":"3 Bytes",
         "B":"32 Bits",
         "C":"64 Bits",
         "D":"12 Bytes"
      }
   },
   "1":{  
      "QUESTION":"Which one is not a SFR",
      "OPTION":{  
         "A":"PC",
         "B":"R1",
         "C":"SBUF"
      }
   },
   "2":{  
      "QUESTION":"What is Size of DPTR in 8051",
      "OPTION":{  
         "A":"16 Bits",
         "B":"8 Bytes",
         "C":"8 Bits"
      }
   },
   "3":{  
      "QUESTION":"Is to_string() is valid builtin function prior to c++11 ? ",
      "OPTION":{  
         "A":"Yes",
         "B":"No"
      }
   }
}
```

The obvious solution is to parse it query using JOIN and convert it to JSON.
Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Do you have access to php at all? It has a nice json_encode function. Be easy enough to connect to MySQL from php

Comment: Your JSON seems sub-optimal to me. Are the number keys at the top level ids or just indexes? Il the latter case, replace that with an array, it’ll make more sense. As for the processing itself, just loop over the results and either create a new object when you find a new question, or add to the OPTIONS if the question already exists (I.e. it’s the same as the last one you saw or added). You could use a simple loop, or use `reduce` to do that. One your have your data just `JSON.stringify` it (or output it with `res.json` if using Express).

Comment: Note: if the question involved PostgreSQL rather than MySQL you could easily do all that in SQL with arrays and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can achieve this with group_concat

tablenames, fieldnames, etc are pure fantasy :-)

```
select
    q.text as question,
    group_concat(answer.label, ';;;') as labels,
    group_concat(answer.text, ';;;') as answers
from
    question as q
    join answer as a on a.quesion = q.id
group by
    q.text
```

And then in your application (nodejs)

```
let resultRows = callSomeFunctionsThatReturnesAllRowsAsArray();
let properStructure = resultRows.map(row => {
    let texts = row.answers.split(';;;');
    return {
        question: row.question,
        options: row.labels.split(';;;').map((label, index) => {label: label, answer: texts[index]});
    }
});
```

Comment: Very useful , One Improvement  using `group_concat(answer.label, ';;;')`  generated empty value in last position when splitted in javascript however using
 `group_concat(answer.label SEPARATOR  ';;;')`  was a easy fix